# my new name on github is not reconized on github even its the same

Tags: git, github

I have changed my username on github, when I do

```
git config --global user.name
```

I get my new name but if I push anything its not reconized as a user on github. An idea why ?

Thank you

Comment: That field is for your *actual name*, it has nothing to do with your github username.

Comment: so how can link my local and the github one otherwise

Comment: Have you tried changing it through the github web? When you go to Settings/Account there is a section for changing your username.

Comment: Yes i did that is why is so weird

Comment: check your if your repo specific configs and global configs are same are not
git config --list 
git config --list --global